# node.js cannot find 'auth_token' in cookies. Keeps throwing TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, jwt

I am trying to verify that a user has a Json Web Token before accessing a static page. Below is the code I have to do that. My problem is I am not able to find the JWT in the browsers cookies. I end up with a TypeError you will find at the bottom of this post. I know my code is working because I can manually add the jwt token into the header with postman and it works.

verifyToken.js

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = function(req,res,next){
        const token = req.cookies.auth_token;
        if (!token) {
            return res.status(403).send('Access Denied');
        }
        try{
            const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
            req.user = verified;
            return next();
        } catch (err) {
            res.clearCookie('token');
            res.status(403).send('Invalid Token');
        }
    };
```

auth.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../model/User');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const {registerValidation, loginValidation} = require('../validation');
const { redirect } = require('express/lib/response');

//Register New User
router.post('/register', async (req,res) => {

    //Validate the data before creating user
    const {error} = registerValidation(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    //Checking if user already exist in database
    const emailExist = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
    if(emailExist) return res.status(400).send('Email already exists');

    //Hash the password for secruity
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

    //Create a new user
    const user = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hashedPassword
    });
    res.redirect('/login')
    try{
        const savedUser = await user.save();
        res.send({user: user._id});
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).send(err);
    }
});

//Login
router.post('/login', async (req,res) => {
    const {error} = loginValidation(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    //Checking if eamil exist in database
    const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
    if(!user) return res.status(400).send('Email or password does not exists');

    //Check if password is correct
    const validPass= await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if(!validPass) return res.status(400).send('Invalid password')
    
    //Creat and assign json web token
    const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);

 res.cookie('auth_token', token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        // secure: false,
        // maxAge: 1000000,
        // signed: true,
    })
    //res.header('auth-token', token);
    //Redirects you to welcome page after successful login
    res.redirect('/welcome');
});

module.exports = router;
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth_token' of undefined
at module.exports (D:\coding-stuff\Web Dev\Node.js\Node.js_Authenticator\routes\verifyToken.js:4:35)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\coding-stuff\Web Dev\Node.js\Node.js_Authenticator\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (D:\coding-stuff\Web Dev\Node.js\Node.js_Authenticator\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (D:\coding-stuff\Web Dev\Node.js\Node.js_Authenticator\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\coding-stuff\Web Dev\Node.js\Node.js_Authenticator\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at D:\coding-stuff\Web Dev\Node.js\Node.js_Authenticator\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (D:\coding-stuff\Web Dev\Node.js\Node.js_Authenticator\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (D:\coding-stuff\Web Dev\Node.js\Node.js_Authenticator\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at urlencodedParser (D:\coding-stuff\Web Dev\Node.js\Node.js_Authenticator\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:91:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\coding-stuff\Web Dev\Node.js\Node.js_Authenticator\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

EDIT:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const router = require('express')();
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
router.use(cookieParser());
module.exports = function(req,res,next){
        const token = req.header('Cookie');
        if (!token) {
            return res.status(403).send('Access Denied');
        }
        try{
            const verified = req.header('Cookie');
            req.user = verified;
            // const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
            // req.user = verified;
             next();
        } catch (err) {
            res.clearHeader;
            res.status(403).send('Invalid Token');
        }
    };
```

This code works the only problem being it is only checking to see if there is a cookie in the response header not if that cookie contains a valid JWT. My question now is how do I make this code more specific to look for a valid JWT?

Comment: Did you use router.use(express.cookieParser()) before the others router?

Comment: Make sure that you're imported const express = require('express')

Comment: @AmanurRahman no I did not use router.use(express.cookieParser()) before any other routers. I have also imported express.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use [cookie-parser](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html)

```
const router = require('express')();
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const User = require('../model/User');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const {registerValidation, loginValidation} = require('../validation');
const { redirect } = require('express/lib/response');

router.use(cookieParser())
...
```

For .cookies to be available, assuming you're using node 14.x it might be worth using optional chaining too

eg

```
const token = req?.cookies?.auth_token;
```

Comment: This fixies my TypeError but I do not think it is actually looking for the auth_token in my cookies because it no longer works when I use PostMan like it use to now I just get access denied which means there is !token in the cookies. Even though there is when I look in my browser.

Comment: Hey @AlexanderMurdock it's really hard to give you a better answer without your full source code, looks like you've got a lot of moving parts so I created a working example 
here: https://github.com/JamesMahy/SO-69338984-cookie-jwt-problem 

There is also a public postman collection in the Readme file you can use.